# Advantage of flask-testing over unittest.TestCase

Tags: python, flask

I see at various places `flask-testing` being used. What advantages does it have over simply using `unittest.TestCase` which is provided by Python.

Answer (score 2):

`flask_testing.TestCase` just extends `unittest.TestCase`:

1. [assert_template_used](https://github.com/jarus/flask-testing/blob/master/flask_testing/utils.py#L127);
2. [assert_context](https://github.com/jarus/flask-testing/blob/master/flask_testing/utils.py#L166)
3. [assert_redirects](https://github.com/jarus/flask-testing/blob/master/flask_testing/utils.py#L183)
4. [assert_status](https://github.com/jarus/flask-testing/blob/master/flask_testing/utils.py#L196)

This package also contains:
http://flask-testing.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#testing-with-liveserver, http://flask-testing.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#using-with-twill.

More details you can get from [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/) and [github repo](https://github.com/jarus/flask-testing/).